# reactstrap components not working typescript

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

My code looks like this:

```
import { Alert } from 'reactstrap';

const test: React.FC = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Alert></Alert>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But then I get this error:

```
"message": "'Alert' cannot be used as a JSX component.\n  Its instance type 'Alert' is not a valid JSX element.\n    Type 'Alert' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.",
```

I get this message on every other reactstrap component

How can I fix this?